# Deploy Oracle APEX application using slqplus commands

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, oracle-apex, sqlplus

I am trying to import APEX application using Jenkins pipeline. I found these sqlplus commands in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_app_inst.htm#AEAPI560) but couldn't run it. Jenkins starts to run sqlplus commands and stops at this point:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m
Oracle SQL Developer Command-Line (SQLcl) help 
Usage 1: sql -H | -V
......
```

Looks like before the import application commands, I need to write some connection commands which I dont know. Do you guys know how to run these commands and deploy APEX application?

Comment: Can you expand on what "couldn't run it" means?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?

Comment: @JustinCave I have edited just now. Sqlplus has started to run but before APEX import commands I need some other command which provides connection I think.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://insum.ca/oracle-apex-deployments-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the commands what I need and looks like its working. I can deploy an APEX application with this command:

```
/tools/sqlcl/bin/sql -s username/password@databaseName @f101.sql
```

I assummed that we have already exported an application with name 101 and you can import it with this command. It also works in Jenkins pipeline.